# pandas merge data based on many columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

having two dataframes of sizes 3210(trial) and 110(distincts), filled with the following

|  | WallpaperColor | MaxScores | ParentalContact | ClassNumber | Class | ClassLabelColor | StudentSize | GirlToBoyRatio | Brightness | EffectiveLearningScore | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Red | 5000 | 2 | 3 | F | White | Small | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | Red | 600 | 1 | 2 | G | Yellow | Small | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | Black | 200 | 1 | 5 | G | Yellow | Big | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | Blue | 2000 | 1 | 1 | M | Red | Small | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | Blue | 200 | 1 | 8 | K | Orange | Small | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

and

|  | Class | ClassNumber | GirlToBoyRatio | Brightness | EffectiveLearningScore | ClassLabelColor | StudentSize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | F | 0 | 1.400 | 5.10 | 7610.0 | White | Small |
| 1 | F | 1 | 1.355 | 4.45 | 7325.0 | Yellow | Small |
| 2 | F | 2 | 1.300 | 4.10 | 7040.0 | Yellow | Big |
| 3 | F | 3 | 1.270 | 3.80 | 6865.0 | White | Big |
| 4 | F | 4 | 1.230 | 3.20 | 6690.0 | White | Small |

so I want to merge data so that if one row of the first table has typically the same values in the second table in the specific `columns = ['ClassNumber', 'ClassName', 'ClassLabelColor', 'StudentSize']` then it fills out the [ratio, brightness,ELS] columns with values in the second table instead of NaNs and set the type to distinct while any other row type to be set as ordinnary,

I've tried doing this with

```
for i in range(len(trial[columns])):
  if trial.iloc[i] == distincts[columns].iloc[i]:
      trial.iloc[i]['type'] = "distinct"
```

also tried doing it with
`trial.merge(distincts, how='outer')`

but the first one takes forever to finish and kept running for more than 40 minutes,
the other one outputed values based on only the first column in the list of columns and kept replicating values based on it making all the 3210 rows filled with values instead of only 110 of it, but adding extra 11 columns Idk why to the 3210 making them 3221

Answer (score 0):

From your data, we can build the following :

First we can drop the `'GirlToBoyRatio', 'Brightness',  'EffectiveLearningScore', 'type'` columns in `trial` :

```py
>>> trial = trial.drop(['GirlToBoyRatio', 'Brightness',  'EffectiveLearningScore', 'type'], axis=1)
>>> trial
    WallpaperColor  MaxScores   ParentalContact Class Number    Class   ClassLabelColor StudentSize
0   Red             5000        2               3               F       White           small
1   Red             600         1               2               G       Yellow          small
2   Black           200         1               5               F       Yellow          big
3   Blue            2000        1               1               M       Red             small
4   Blue            200         1               8               K       Orange          small
```

Then, we merge the `trial` DataFrame with the `distincts` one :

```py
>>> df = pd.merge(trial,
...               distincts,
...               how='left',
...               on= ['Class Number', 'Class', 'ClassLabelColor', 'StudentSize'])
>>> df
    WallpaperColor  MaxScores   ParentalContact Class Number    Class   ClassLabelColor StudentSize GirlToBoyRatio  Brightness      EffectiveLearningScore
0   Red             5000        2               3               F       White           small       1.27            3.8             6865.0
1   Red             600         1               2               G       Yellow          small       NaN             NaN             NaN
2   Black           200         1               5               F       Yellow          big         1.33            3.7             8710.0
3   Blue            2000        1               1               M       Red             small       NaN             NaN             NaN
4   Blue            200         1               8               K       Orange          small       NaN             NaN             NaN
```

To finish, we add the `type` column to get the expected result :

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df['type'] = np.where((df['GirlToBoyRatio'].isna()) & (df['Brightness'].isna()) & (df['EffectiveLearningScore'].isna()), np.nan, 'distinct')
>>> df
    WallpaperColor  MaxScores   ParentalContact Class Number    Class   ClassLabelColor StudentSize GirlToBoyRatio  Brightness      EffectiveLearningScore   type
0   Red             5000        2               3               F       White           small       1.27            3.8             6865.0                   distinct
1   Red             600         1               2               G       Yellow          small       NaN             NaN             NaN                      NaN
2   Black           200         1               5               F       Yellow          big         1.33            3.7             8710.0                   distinct
3   Blue            2000        1               1               M       Red             small       NaN             NaN             NaN                      NaN
4   Blue            200         1               8               K       Orange          small       NaN             NaN             NaN                      NaN
```

Comment: why not only `on` ?

Comment: Indeed, it would be even sorter. Thanks @jez  :) !

Comment: @tlentali, I've tried this too, kept doing the same as trial.merge(distincts) without the left and right ons parameters

Comment: Hi @AhmedSeif, can you share a sample of data your are expecting in output please, I will check it :)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zbRVkWrIlGrO4ueXETIuLKRMzZOU-DIrYJsol5FuVsE/edit?usp=sharing

I've created a spreadsheet on google drive illustrating the expected output, thank you for your time

Comment: Thanks for sharing the expected result, I updated the answer :) !